# Removing all the characters (a-z, A-Z) from a string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, reference, character

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string moveString(string t, int index)
{
    for (int i=index; t[i]!=NULL;i++)
    {
        t[i]=t[i+1];
    }
    return t;
}

string delChars(string t)
{
    for (int i=0; t[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        if (t[i]>'a' && t[i]<'z')
        {
            moveString(t, i);
        }
        else if (t[i]>'A' && t[i]<'Z')
        {
            moveString(t, i);
        }
    }
    return t;
}

int main()
{
    int numberOfSpaces;
    string t;
    cout << "Text some word: "; cin>>t;
    cout<<delChars(t);
    return 0;
}
```

First function `moveString` should (in theory) take down every single character from a string by 1 index down (starting from given index) - to remove 1 character. The rest is pretty obvious. But:

Input: `abc123def`
Output: `abc123def`

What am I doing wrong?

And a additional mini-question: Acutally, what's the best way to "delete" an element from an array? (array of `int`s, `char`s, etc.)

Comment: ...[`std::remove_copy_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy)?

Answer (score 2):

`moveString` takes `t` by value and you're not assigning its return value, so it doesn't change `t` in `delChars`. So, make sure the next thing you learn are references.

Apart from that, I don't know what to tell about `t[i] != NULL` (if it is undefined behavior or not), but we have `std::string::size` to get the length of `std::string`, e.g. `i < t.size()`. And if you have`t[i + 1]`, the condition should then be `i + 1 < t.size()`.

Whatever, don't play with it like with `char` arrays, leaving the string with previous size. You can `pop_back` the last (duplicate) character after shifting the characters.

It's worth mentioning that it can be done in one line of idiomatic C++ algorithms, but you want to get your code working...

Answer (score 2):

Logic Stuff is right but his answer is not enough. You shouldn't increase `i` after `move`. Since the `i.th character` is removed and `i` points to the next character now.

```
string delChars(string t)
{
    for (int i=0; t[i]!=NULL; )
    {
        if (t[i]>'a' && t[i]<'z')
        {
            t = moveString(t, i);
        }
        else if (t[i]>'A' && t[i]<'Z')
        {
            t = moveString(t, i);
        }
        else
           i++;
    }
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Not using standard algorithms

> Actually, what's the best way to "delete" an element from array? (array of ints, chars, etc.)

By using the standard remove-erase idiom:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto s = "!the 54 quick brown foxes jump over the 21 dogs."s;
    cout << "before: " << quoted(s) << endl;

    s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(),
                           s.end(),
                           [](auto c) { return std::isalpha(c); }),
                               s.end());

    cout << "after: " << quoted(s) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
before: "!the 54 quick brown foxes jump over the 21 dogs."
after: "! 54       21 ."
```

> I'm not allowed to use standard algorithms

Then keep it simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>


std::string remove_letters(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(input.size());

    for (auto c : input) {
        if (!std::isalpha(c)) {
            result.push_back(c);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    auto s = "!the 54 quick brown foxes jump over the 21 dogs."s;
    cout << "before: " << quoted(s) << endl;

    auto s2 = remove_letters(s);

    cout << "after: " << quoted(s2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a homework, not new brand project. I am not allowed to use those methods